# Invert the wheel or keyboard arrow function in QDateTimeEdit

Tags: qt

I am using the QDateTimeEdit to let the user select a date and time. Is there a way that I can invert the response to the mouse wheel and keyboard arrows ?

For example, the default setting causes the up-arrow press (or scroll up) to increment the time or date. Can I change this setting such that scroll up causes the time/date to decrease ?

(I am a rank newbie to QT, so please let me know if this has been answered before !)

Answer (score 0):

As a hint, you need to re-implement those virtual functions:

```
void keyPressEvent ( QKeyEvent * event )
void mousePressEvent ( QMouseEvent * event )
```